# Getting type from list of icomparable

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface

I have a dictionary of `<string, IComparable>` which means the value could Pretty much contain any value type.

Now when I update the value I want to convert a string input to the original type.  I have tried all manner of converts but I don't seem to be having any success.

Example
    
    Dictionary  val = new Dictionary ();
    Val.Add ("test", 1);
    Val ["test"]="44"; //this is where I tried convert. But it's not always an int.

So if pre update the value was an int then it will be stored as an int. If it is a byte then it will be stored as an byte.

Can anyone point me in the right direction

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to convert here. Please improve the description and add sample input and expected result.

Comment: What do you mean by original type?

Answer (score 0):

```
string id = "type";
val.Add(id, 1);
var type = val[id].getType();
val[id] = System.Convert.ChangeType("44", type);
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried. However that just returned the type as Icomparable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know all the data types that will be used (int, byte etc), you could use the typeof operator to check for the type before, and then cast to that type from your data.

```
if (typeof(Val["test]) == int)
{
    Val["test"] = int.parse("44");
}
```